# Firestore Rules For Admin

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Good day!
Wrote rules for Firestore:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignIn() {
        return request.auth.uid != null
    }
  
    function isAdmin() {
        return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/admins/$(request.auth.uid))
    }
    
    function isPublished() {
        return resource.data.published == true
    }

    match /instructions/{instructionId} {
      allow list:
        if isSignIn()
            &&  (isPublished() || isAdmin())
            &&  request.query.limit <= 10
    }
  }
}
```

I know that rules are not filters. I want to achieve a condition under which an administrator can view both published posts and unpublished posts, while regular users can only see published posts. The presence of a check for `published` forces the condition to be set at the application level.

```
firestore.collection("instructions")
   .whereEqualTo("published", true)
   .limit(10)
   .get()
```

Which, in principle, is logical if we want to show only published posts to ordinary users.

How can I make the administrator see all records?
I have only one option - to remove the condition `isPublished () || isAdmin ()` and make a separate view for the administrator without a publication condition. In this case, verification will have to be done on the client side, which is not good.

What can you advise?

Answer (score 1):

=> You can save yourself some costs by using custom claims on the user account to identify privileged users (they come in on the `context.auth` object), rather than reading from a document.  It requires some backend/cloud function code (custom claims can only be added to the user token from privileged/secure environments), but this is the approach I use extensively - no trusting of the client at all.  Works best with a "login" style approach to privileges, relatively long lasting, so you don't invoke Cloud Functions too often.

=> the `.whereEqualTo("published", true)` is actually zero cost for the client - and since any request for documents that do NOT have published set will fail, there is no security risk - properly formed requests will succeed; poorly formed/deliberately malformed requests will fail (hence, "rules are not filters").

=> a separate rule for `isAdmin()` is perfectly reasonable and expected - if ANY rule matches, permission is granted; it doesn't have to be in the SAME rule.

Comment: That is, two rules can be made?
```allow list: if isSignIn() && isPublished() && request.query.limit <= 10```
and
```allow list: if isSignIn() && isAdmin() && request.query.limit <= 10```
How true will this be?

Comment: Absolutely.  Whatever makes it legible.  Firebase/Firestore just checks rules until it finds one that permits the transaction.